# Mongodb java Query Builder

Tags: java, mongodb, query-builder, mongo-java

I am new to java. How can I build this mongo query in java. Any help/hint will be appreciated.

```
db.places.find({loc : { $near :[ -122.934326171875,37.795268017578] , $maxDistance : 50 } ,$or:[{"uid":"at"},{"myList.$id" :ObjectId("4fdeaeeede2d298262bb80") } ] ,"searchTag" : { $regex : "Union", $options: "i"} } );
```

Comment: what you have tried uptil now to implement it. Can you show us ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the [QueryBuilder](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.2/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html) you can create the query you wanted. I have created it as follows.

```
QueryBuilder query = new QueryBuilder();
query.put("loc").near(-122.934326171875, 37.795268017578, 50);
query.or(
        QueryBuilder.start("uid").is("at").get(),
        QueryBuilder.start("myList.$id").is(new ObjectId("5024f2f577a59dd9736ddc38")).get()
            );
query.put("searchTag").regex(Pattern.compile("Union",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
```

When I print the query into the console it looks like :

```
{ "loc" : { "$near" : [ -122.934326171875 , 37.795268017578 , 50.0]} , 
  "$or" : [ { "uid" : "at"} , { "myList.$id" : { "$oid" : "5024f2f577a59dd9736ddc38"}}] , 
  "searchTag" : { "$regex" : "Union" , "$options" : "i"}
}
```

I didn't try it but hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me try and get back to you.